# how to dynamically place lat, lon data onto a topoJSON map

Tags: d3.js

I have a topoJSON map of the counties of WV. It is a display of population densities correctly. This map was created from geoJSON data and then converted using  topojson. This is all the normal steps that developers take to create a static display of their data. My problem now, is that users of this map will want to place data on it and they only have lat,lon values. How can I display lat, lon data on a previously created topoJSON map?

Here is some sample data:

```
var sampleData = [
    {"name": "Weirton", "coordinates": [-80.589517, 40.418957]},
    {"name": "Morgantown", "coordinates": [-79.955897, 39.629526]},
    {"name": "Shepherdstown", "coordinates": [-77.804161, 39.430100]}              
];
```

That I have tried to display on my (already displayed) map, like this:

```
var group = svg.append('g');

group.selectAll("cities")
   .data(sampleData)
   .enter()
      .append("cities")
          .attr("class", "cities")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + projection(d.coordinates) + ")";});
```

Is it possible to get some lat,lon data onto a static map or have I mad some programming error?

UPDATE: I have played with the data and discovered that using this code:

```
svg.append("path")
.datum(topojson.feature(wv, dynamicData))
.attr("d", path)
.attr("class", "place")
```

works with this data

```
var dynamicData = 
{
    "type":"GeometryCollection",    
    "geometries":[
        {"type":"Point","properties":{"NAME":"Weirton"},"id":"Weirton","coordinates":[4172,9359]},
        {"type":"Point","properties":{"NAME":"Morgantown"},"id":"Morgantown","coordinates":[5458,7063]},
        {"type":"Point","properties":{"NAME":"Shepherdstown"},"id":"Shepherdstown","coordinates":[9826,6483]}]
};
```

but does not work with this data

```
var dynamicData = 
{
    "type":"GeometryCollection",    
    "geometries":[
        {"type":"Point","properties":{"NAME":"Weirton"},"id":"Weirton","coordinates":[-80.589517, 40.418957]},
        {"type":"Point","properties":{"NAME":"Morgantown"},"id":"Morgantown","coordinates":[-79.955897, 39.629526]},
        {"type":"Point","properties":{"NAME":"Shepherdstown"},"id":"Shepherdstown","coordinates":[-77.804161, 39.430100]}]
};
```

Can someone show me how to calculate the new coordinates?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle or Plunkr or something so we can see exactly what you're doing?

Comment: Well, my problem there is I can't get my topoJSON file on JSFiddle. At least I'm not aware of how to do that.

Comment: if I run my original lat/lon data through topojson and view the output, I get {"name": "Weirton",   "coordinates": [4172,9359]}. How did topojson compute these values? I may be able to continue if I can do the same computations for my dynamic data.

Comment: These are simply the coordinates in a different projection. You can project coordinates that the user gives you completely independently provided you've set up the projection correctly.

Answer (score 0):

ok, it turns out that this snippet of code will display my lat/lon data correctly

```
svg.selectAll(".geojson").data([sampleData4])
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("class","geojson")
.attr("d", path)
;
```

(sampleData4 is my lat/lon data (i.e. dynamicData) above in my edit. I stumbled on this after many google searches. I found this snippet at

```
http://hashbang.co.nz/blog/2013/2/25/d3_js_geo_fun
```

I would appreciate anyone's explanation of why it worked and why all my previous work didn't. I am also still very interested in understanding (with a detailed specific example) of how the coord conversion actually works.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem but that link no longer works.  Do you have any tips on how you resolved the problem?